# Memory Allocation with Nodes in C

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, block

I'm creating malloc for a project, and allocating space the hard way to understand how it works, but I'm getting null pointer issues.

(given) Block Structure: Linked List

```
 typedef struct block_hd{
  /* The blocks are maintained as a linked list */
  /* The blocks are ordered in the increasing order of addresses */
  struct block_hd* next;

  int size_status;

 }block_header;

block_header* list_head = NULL;
```

When I'm adding memory blocks, I'm running into an error with my temp Node. Basically, it's not dereferencing temp_node to get to its next and set it to the proper location. 
My print out statements:

```
 not empty: 4088
 there is space to add
 create temp
 f7758040
 f7754000
 00000000
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It's never getting to temp_node's next. Like it's not creating temp properly. Temp is pointing to headers of blocks. And I'm giving it a location. What is the problem?

My Mem_Alloc function *assume properly initiated linked list:

```
void* Mem_Alloc(int size)
{
if (size < 1) return NULL;
size = 1 + ((size - 1)/4);
size = size * 4;

if (list_head != NULL){

    block_header* head_node = list_head; 

    while (head_node != NULL){
        //get curr header size
        int node_size = head_node->size_status;



        printf("not empty: %d\n", node_size);

            //there is space to add
            if (node_size%2 == 0 && (size+sizeof(block_header)) < node_size){
                printf("there is space to add\n");                  

                //twocases
                if ((node_size - size - sizeof(block_header)) > 0){
                        printf("create temp\n");                        
                        block_header* temp_node = NULL;
                        temp_node = head_node + sizeof(block_header) + size;
                        printf("%08x\n", (unsigned int) temp_node);
                        printf("%08x\n", (unsigned int) head_node);
                        printf("%08x\n", (unsigned int) head_node->next);
                        printf("%08x\n", (unsigned int) temp_node->next);
                        printf("set temp next to head next\n");
                        temp_node->next = head_node->next;
                        printf("set temp size to remaining\n");
                        temp_node->size_status = (head_node->size_status - sizeof(block_header) - size);
                        printf("set head size to used status\n");
                        head_node->size_status = size + 1;
                        printf("set head next to temp\n");
                        head_node->next = temp_node;
                    }
                    else{
                        //if at end, and not enough space for another header
                        //keep current size_status - do not reduce current 
                        printf("Not enough space, set head size to used\n");
                        if (head_node->next != NULL) head_node->size_status = size + 1;

                    }


                //return location of (head_node_location+sizeof(block_header))
                return head_node + sizeof(block_header);    
            }//end if

            else{
                //headersize%2 equaled 1, so it's used - move on.
                printf("STEPPING THROUGH LINKED LIST\n");
                head_node = head_node->next;
            }
    }//end while
}//end if
return NULL;
```

Comment: Use a debugger ... SO is a not a substitute for one.

Comment: The problem with that: this is within a library, so there are no line numbers to step through for GDB. It's difficult to get it to work properly, so I just started with print outs to locate the issue.

Comment: Got the source code? If so recompile for the debugger

Comment: This is a library you're writing, and you have the source for, right? If you build it with the right flags you will have line number and other debugging information. If that's too difficult, just compile your malloc as a static object file together with a main() to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`temp_node` is set here:

```
temp_node = head_node + sizeof(block_header) + size;
```

Incrementing pointers doesn't go by bytes, the addresses are calculated according to the type the pointer points to. So if `p` points to element 0 of an array of `struct block_struct`, then `p+1` will point to the `struct block_struct` at index 1 and `p+2` will point to the one at index 2.

The initialization of `temp_node` seems to assume that `head_node` will be incremented by a number of bytes.

You can either change your calculations to work on `struct block_struct`s or you can cast your pointers to `char*` before doing the pointer arithmetic (`char` is one byte).

Comment: so like 
    temp_node = ((char*)head_node) + sizeof(block_header) + size;

Comment: Or am I misunderstanding? What I get, and facepalmed about: adding pointers. I need to cast as chars to get proper indexing. *check* But doing the above results in: mem.c:138: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

Answer (score 1):

You're getting tripped up by how pointer arithmetic interacts with types.

`temp_node = head_node + sizeof(block_header) + size;`

I assume that in this line you are trying to advance the pointer `size + sizeof(block_header)` bytes. But since the pointers are to block_headers, it is advancing by that byte count times the sizeof(block_header). You could do something like:

```
/* Advance the pointer then cast */
char *raw_tmp_node = head_node + sizeof(block_header) + size;
block_header *tmp_node = (block_header*)raw_tmp_node;
```

As an aside, you should read up on the importance of memory alignment. `malloc` guarantees that the memory it returns is suitably aligned for any type. Generally, this is done by forcing the alignment with a union, as mentioned in K&R.

```
union align_storage {
    most_strictly_aligned_type x; /* Usually a long; sometimes long long */
    char storage[BLOCK_SIZE];
};
```

Comment: so like *temp_node = ((char*)head_node) + sizeof(block_header) + size; *
  
Or am I misunderstanding? What I get, and facepalmed about: adding pointers. I need to cast as chars to get proper indexing. *check* But doing the above results in: *mem.c:138: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type*

Comment: Picked up my K&R, makes much more sense. Thanks!

Comment: @katiea: Right. The reason this is especially useful is because depending on the system you're targeting, the structure layout and size might differ, so it's convenient to have the compiler do the arithmetic for you. Your line could be:

`temp_node = (block_header*)(((char*)head_node) + sizeof(block_header) + size);`

But that's a lot more nesting parens :)